# MySQL Query Between Dates

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cron

I have a website based on PHP and MySQL database

I am needing looking to be able to run a weekly report via running a cron job, To display all items between two dates, automatically without any user interaction to change the dates.

The dates would be todays date minus 7 days.

I have tried this script but can't seem to find the fault

The table is pc_wo and the field the data is in is 'pickupdate'

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `pc_wo` WHERE `pickupdate` BETWEEN CURDATE() -DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-7 AND CURDATE() -DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
```

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) combined with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `pc_wo` WHERE `pickupdate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The important part being:

```
DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```